# How to trigger an event when the application wakes up from the background?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

How do I trigger an event when the application wakes up from the background in [Appcelerator Titanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appcelerator_Titanium) mobile?

Comment: if its javascript and browser then it is `window.onfocus`.. dont know about in titanium mobile..

Comment: Thanks, I am afraid that titanium is different than browser based frameworks, thanks

Answer (score 5):

add an eventListener for the "resumed" event

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("resumed", function(e){
});
```